# Image zoom WITH pixelation

Tags: vb.net, winforms, image

I am zooming image in picture box using this code on trackbar.

```
Private Sub tbrZoomLevel_Scroll(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles tbrZoomLevel.Scroll
    With pbImage
        .SuspendLayout()
        .Width = actualSize.Width * tbrZoomLevel.Value
        .Height = actualSize.Height * tbrZoomLevel.Value
        .ResumeLayout()
    End With
End Sub
```

pbImage is a PictureBox control with sizemode as zoom.
actualSize is original Size of Image in pbImage.

When I zoom in, I get image without pixelation. But I want it to get fully pixelated and show the image as shown in MS Paint on zooming. Any help is appreciated. VB.Net code, C# code or just any algorithm is welcomed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your picturebox paint:

```
Private Sub PictureBox1_Paint(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Paint

    e.Graphics.InterpolationMode = Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor
    'Draw the image
End Sub
```

Edit: Try this

```
Private Sub PictureBox1_Paint(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Paint
    Dim srcRect As RectangleF = New Rectangle(0, 0, PictureBox1.Width / 8, PictureBox1.Height / 8)
    Dim dstRect As RectangleF = New RectangleF(0, 0, PictureBox1.Width, PictureBox1.Height)

    e.Graphics.InterpolationMode = Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(pctBoxImage, dstRect, srcRect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel)
End Sub
```

`pctBoxImage` is the `bitmap` which will be `800% zoomed`

or

```
Private Sub PictureBox1_Paint(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Paint
    e.Graphics.ScaleTransform(8, 8)
    e.Graphics.InterpolationMode = Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(pctBoxImage, 0, 0)
End Sub
```

`0,0` is the coordinates of the left up corner position **on** the bitmap.

valter

Comment: I want the image to properly show its pixels when it is zoomed in same as in MS paint on zooming. Interpolation is just opposite to this. Take picture in MS paint, zoom in uptu 600 or 800 %, you will see the pixels are becoming larger square. I want the same behavior.

Comment: @Sarvesh It is exactly as you need. You will see pixels. See my edit